# Is it possible to enable GRPC message compression in server? (Python)

Tags: python, compression, protocol-buffers, rpc, grpc

I have a gRPC client (in Java) sending requests to a server (written in Python). I need to enable both request compression and response compression. There is good [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/2204) on how to enable compression on the client side. I have managed to compress the request like so:

```
 response = blockingStub.withCompression("gzip").method(request)
```

However, I cannot find any documentation on how to compress the server response (also). It seems that there is almost no documentation (or examples) on how to use gRPC message compression in Python. How can I enable server-side compression? The call is a simple RPC call (no streaming).

Answer (score 0):

Compression in Python is supported via metadata arguments.

You can find an example here:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/unit/_compression_test.py

Answer (score 0):

To add to [kpayson64's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50844316/33708) which covers call-level compression, you can set compression settings on a `grpc.Channel` or `grpc.Server` object upon initialization via the channel arg [`grpc.default_compression_algorithm`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/compression_types.h#L39).

Please also see the [gRPC Compression Cookbook](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/compression_cookbook.md) on recommendations on where to or not to explicitly enable compression.