# What is the state of compression support in gRPC for Python?

Tags: python, compression, grpc

I am attempting to implement a gRPC client and server using the Python gRPC implementation as a reference.

According to the spec document at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/compression.md there are several use-cases that should be supported:

> Compression MAY be configured by the Client Application by calling the
>   appropriate API method. There are two scenarios where compression MAY
>   be configured:
>
> - At channel creation time, which sets the channel default compression
>     and therefore the compression that SHALL be used in the absence of
>     per-RPC compression configuration.
> - At response time, via: For unary
>     RPCs, the {Client,Server}Context instance. For streaming RPCs, the
>     {Client,Server}Writer instance. In this case, configuration is reduced
>     to disabling compression altogether.
>
> ...
>
> Compression Method Asymmetry Between Peers
>
> A gRPC peer MAY choose to
>   respond using a different compression method to that of the request,
>   including not performing any compression, regardless of channel and
>   RPC settings (for example, if compression would result in small or
>   negative gains).
>
> ...
>
> Specific Disabling of Compression
>
> If the user (through the previously
>   described mechanisms) requests to disable compression the next message
>   MUST be sent uncompressed. This is instrumental in preventing
>   BEAST/CRIME attacks. This applies to both the unary and streaming
>   cases.

Some of these seem to be possible, and others not. Tackling them one by one, here is what I think is possible:

> - At channel creation time, which sets the channel default compression
>     and therefore the compression that SHALL be used in the absence of
>     per-RPC compression configuration.

This works. On the server you can specify:

```
from grpc._cython.cygrpc import CompressionAlgorithm, CompressionLevel

server_options = [(
     "grpc.default_compression_algorithm", CompressionAlgorithm.gzip
),(
     "grpc.default_compression_level", CompressionLevel.high
)]

server = grpc.server(
    futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10), options=server_options
)
```

And on the client:

```
from grpc._cython.cygrpc import CompressionAlgorithm

channel_options = [(
     "grpc.default_compression_algorithm", CompressionAlgorithm.gzip
)]

channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
    "127.0.0.1:{}".format(port), options=channel_options
)
```

This correctly sets up the default algorithms on both sides.

You can override the compression algorithm for a specific call by setting the `grpc-internal-encoding-request` metadata key:

```
stub.MethodName(request, metadata={'grpc-internal-encoding-request': 'gzip'})
```

This is ultimately sets the `grpc-encoding` header on the request and the body is encoded appropriately.

So far so good. Next:

> Compression Method Asymmetry Between Peers
>
> A gRPC peer MAY choose to
>   respond using a different compression method to that of the request,
>   including not performing any compression, regardless of channel and
>   RPC settings

I found an example of how to do this in this [unit test](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/d0ad7518ba2a015f9b535ab7a9fea2f650cb5762/src/python/grpcio_tests/tests/unit/_compression_test.py#L30-L31) and a referencing [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509606/is-it-possible-to-enable-grpc-message-compression-in-server-python). However, when I try do this I see an error in my logs, and the response header is not changed:

```
prepare_application_metadata: {"created":"@1541795237.323499000","description":"Unallowed duplicate metadata","file":"src/core/lib/transport/metadata_batch.cc","file_line":113,"key":"grpc-internal-encoding-request","value":"gzip"}
```

The error is raised when the server also has a *default* compression algorithm set. When there is no default it does seem to work.

Relatedly, the accepted answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031763/grpc-compression-in-c-sharp) suggests that `grpc-internal-encoding-request` should only be used in the client ( which makes sense given the name)

So I don't know whether there's a bug whereby you can't set a default and an override at the same time, or whether setting `grpc-internal-encoding-request` is genuinely invalid on the server side (and if so how the response encoding *should* be changed)

Finally:

> Specific Disabling of Compression
>
> If the user (through the previously
>   described mechanisms) requests to disable compression the next message
>   MUST be sent uncompressed. This is instrumental in preventing
>   BEAST/CRIME attacks. This applies to both the unary and streaming
>   cases.

[This Github issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/2578) says that this is supported, but it seems only by the client stubs in the `beta` package, even though the referenced commit was merged in 2015. Is support for this still on some kind of roadmap, or have I missed something somewhere?

I don't *have* to use the Python implementation as my reference. Is there a more complete implementation in another language?

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed analysis. I've added notes to our tracking issue for gRPC Python's compression support: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15741. The Python-level API for compression requires some clean up and additions, as you've noticed. gRPC Core (which Python wraps) fully supports all of the per channel/call/message compression options; gRPC Python needs to expose more options in its configuration API and then pass-through these settings to core. Thanks for posting, and please follow up on our Github if you have additional input.

Comment: Thanks @EricG. I have subscribed to the Github issue to monitor progress. What alternative implementation could use as my reference that is more complete?

Comment: The gRPC C++ libraries completely implement the compression spec.

Comment: Thanks @EricG! :)